# Creating QGIS layers in python console vs stand-alone application

Tags: pyqgis

I am having trouble creating a QGIS vector layer in a stand-alone python script while exactly the same code works fine in python console inside QGIS.  The following code results in a proper displayable layer when executed in the python console:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer('/abs/path/buses.shp', 'buses', 'ogr')
```

However, the same line of code results in an invalid layer in a standalone app (other QGIS functionality seems to work fine):

```
# PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

layer = QgsVectorLayer('/abs/path/buses.shp', 'buses', 'ogr')
if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load: ", layer.lastError() # returns empty string
```

It seems to me that there is some problem with QGIS data providers in the stand-alone app.  Is there a way to find out what exactly happens inside QgsVectorLayer() or get a list of active QGIS data providers?

I am using QGIS 1.8 on OSX 10.8.3 with python2.7 from macports.

Comment: When you run your Python code you should see output from QGIS. There should be some lines about loading providers if they fail then something must be setup wrong.

Comment: Also try setting setPrefixPath to `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents`

Comment: Hm..the MacOS folder did not work for me - I assume because I have a homebrew 2.7 Python installation. But - correct me if I m wrong: I assume that the right prefix path should be the folder that contains the folders: "PlugIns, Resources,svg, ... etc" - right? On top of that, the command print QgsApplication.showSettings() gives me back : Application state: QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var: Prefix: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents Plugin Path: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/../PlugIns/qgis Package Data Path: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/../Resources Active Theme Name: Active Theme Path: :/images/th

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your prefix path to /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS.

You can list the providers available using the providerList method of the provider registry:

```
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
providers = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()
for provider in providers:
    print provider
```

To show the current settings, use:

```
print QgsApplication.showSettings()
```

This should match what you see in the Log Messages window, General tab in QGIS. If not, adjust your environment accordingly.

Comment: Yes, setting prefix path to /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS solves the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

But you will encounter many problems because QGIS is made for/uses the standard Apple Python (in/usr/bin) in the Python console and in the Shell and not the MacPorts version, except if you have installed the QGIS version of MacPorts.

Comment: looks like setting prefix path to /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS make the app work for both Apple and MacPorts but python versions is something to keep in mind for future troubleshooting