# Opening vector layer in QGIS Python standalone application?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm working on a project using the QGIS Python API.  I seem to be having some issues with opening a vector layer from a shapefile in my standalone application.  This is the Python script I'm using to test opening the layer:

```
#   Import statements
from qgis.core import *
import os

#   Instantiate the QGIS Application
GUIEnabled = True
app = QgsApplication([], GUIEnabled)
#   Update prefix path
app.setPrefixPath("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True)
app.initQgis()

#   File to be read by the application
vector_source = "absolute_path_to_file"

#   Read layer from file
layer = QgsVectorLayer(vector_source, "Vector_Layer", "ogr")

#   DEBUG: Test if the file path points to a valid file
print "File Path points to a file: ", os.path.isfile(vector_source)

#   DEBUG: Test if the layer initialized correctly
print "Output of layer.isValid(): ", layer.isValid()
```

layer.isValid() returns false when I run the script.  I checked to make sure the file was valid by opening it in the QGIS GUI, which worked.  I also checked out the answer to [Creating QGIS layers in python console vs stand-alone application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59069/creating-qgis-layers-in-python-console-vs-stand-alone-application), but the answer there is specific to Mac users, and I am running on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your **backslashes** when you defined your paths for the QGIS application (I tend to use forward slashes).

So you should replace:

```
app.setPrefixPath("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True)
```

with:

```
app.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
```

or:

```
app.setPrefixPath(r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True)
```

---

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you.  This resolved the issue I was facing.  It's strange that this wasn't a problem in the Python console in QGIS.

Comment: @Benjamin - Most welcome, glad it helped! You mean using single backslashes isn't a problem in the console?

Comment: It wasn't when I tested the code in the console that's in the QGIS GUI

Comment: @Benjamin - Yeah I think QGIS is quite forgiving when it comes to little things like this and solves it automatically. Or atleast that's what I experienced several times =)